# SCCM - Find where collections are referenced

Tags: sccm

Working in SCCM. Before I rebuild a collection I want to make sure I'm aware what other collections/deployments include that collection in a Membership Rule.

I know I can see active deployments that are deployed directly to that collection, but is there a way I can see what other collections may be referencing this collection through the 'Include Collection' Membership rules?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the following? https://mnscug.org/blogs/sherry-kissinger/304-configmgr-2012-sql-report-with-collection-information-about-include-or-exclude-other-collections